# Serve static files with Node.js & Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Although I already browsed some answers both here on SO and the net, I didn't find what I was looking for. I am also a newb in Node.js so perhaps that's the problem.

This is the code that I have and need for starting Node and Socket.IO:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

What I need next would be something like this:

```
http.use(app.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

"app has no method 'static' " is my problem. I tried several other combinations to get both what I read on the net regarding including static css and js and serving httpServer instance to Socket.IO.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

`express.static` is the method you're looking for, not `app.static`, though they would seem identical.

Also, see [this](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js) for an example of an application using both socket.io and express. Note that they only use the `http` server for `socket.io`, not serving the web pages.

Comment: Tried it, says "express is not defined"

Comment: @dnmh Try with the added requires. It's necessary to have the entire express module defined, not just the initiated portion (`app`)

Comment: Now: "path is undefined"

Comment: @dnmh I need to stop assuming requires - sorry. Try with that new require statement.

Comment: Yup, that's it :) Thank you very much, now I can work normally :)